# Android: How do I access my main layout with an id (which i had provided in xml) in my class?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I basically want to access my layout so that I can move onto the next screen when the user clicks anywhere on the present screen.
this is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:id="@+id/hellolayout">
<TextView
    android:text="WELCOME!"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/idiotic_smile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the class, 'hellolayout' is not recognized. Is there anything I'm missing to include?

```
LinearLayout l = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.hellolayout);
```

Comment: you gotta to read the docs.

Comment: I have. Problem is, I can access any buttons/imageviews/child-layouts with an id, but not the parent layout :/
it would be great if someone could help out. I'm new here

Comment: you initialize the linearlayout in the same way you did for buttons and imageviews

Answer (score 0):

Acessing a layout should be as simple as `R.layout.YourLayoutName`. To load it use `setContentView(R.layout.YourLayoutName)`. 
Better refer to the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).